# how to scrapeall pages (page 1 until infinity) on website

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors, scrapy

guys i wanna scrape from [this link](https://n0where.net/)
everythings its okay, my scraping its succes

then i was thinking, how about if i want to scraping all of pages (page one till infinity depends on database article)

i am new to using python and scrapy, before this i using java & c#...their two its so different with python but its okay for me

this is my source

```
import datetime
import urlparse
import socket
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.http import Request

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from thehack.items import NowItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "nowhere"
    allowed_domains = ["n0where.net"]
    start_urls = ["https://n0where.net/"]


    def parse(self, response):
    # Get the next index URLs and yield Requests
        next_selector = response.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/a[8]')
        for url in next_selector.extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url))

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.css('.loop-panel'):
            item = NowItem()
            item['title'] = article.css('.article-title::text').extract_first()
            item['link'] = article.css('.overlay-link::attr(href)').extract_first()
            item['body'] ='' .join(article.css('.excerpt p::text').extract()).strip()
            yield item
```

anybody know how to fix my problem, my source is okay, but its only scraping page 1, how about if i want to scraping next page automatically?

thanks before mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pagination is pretty tough on this website. If you inspect what your browser is doing, you'll see it's making an AJAX POST request with bunch of parameters to https://n0where.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

[image: firebug inspect tab]

You can replicate this request in few ways. One way would be to convert the parameters your inspector shows into a `dict` and create a `scrapy.FormRequest` with it.

```
formdata = {'rating': '', 'layout': 'd', 'excerpt': '1', 'paginated': '2', 'award': '', 'sorter': 'recent', 'disabletrending': '', 'numarticles': '12', 'disablecategory': '', 'meta': '1', 'location': 'loop', 'disablecompare': '', 'action': 'itajax-sort', 'authorship': '', 'size': '', 'badge': '', 'thumbnail': '1', 'loop': 'main', 'icon': '1'}
next_page = 3  # figure out what next page will be
formdata.upadte('paginated': next_page)  # update page
req = FormRequest('https://n0where.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse_next_page)
yield req
```

Now it looks like the response you'll get is a json response with bunch of data, but in short all you want is to get the html code that is in 'content' and parse it as it is your new page.
[image: firebug network tab]

Afterwards rinse and repeat.

Comment: oh my dear, what is it, i just do research(studying scrapping + python) on 2 weeks, and many things i get..

thanks mate, about your answer...i'll try to learn ajax first maybe -_- , its truly harder for beginner programmer like as me to moving from java to c# then python...

btw what application u use on the picture u post?
i'll try your script after i learn ajax, thanks for the answer mate :)

Comment: The page you chose might be a bit difficult for a beginner unforntunately. You might want to take it slow since there a lot of small weird things when it comes to web-scraping that require a bit of disciple to push through. Regarding the software I used here: For inspecting requests I used **Firebug** inspector for firefox and for capturing the screenshot I used **Screencloud**.

Comment: hey mate, can you share me your example source code to scrapping easy page of website which having pagination page one until infinity?
via github/email(rusdizzz1595@gmail.com)/cloud/etc?
thanks so much before mate
today i'll try firebug

Comment: and its why, for 2 days i try scrapping thats website its always fail T_T

Comment: ah, i succes to scrapping website with pagination for simple site mate :)
thanks a lot, for your answer for previous website :)